# C# UWP, get object/page from frame

Tags: c#, asynchronous, binding, uwp, frame

Everybody.

In UWP Windows 10, I want to get the current navigated page in frame as object.
So I can call some methods from that page.

I have main page that is updating some model in async mode, but binding is not updating controls. I need to call:

```
Bindings.Update();
```

on page that is currently navigated in the frame in order to update some TextBlocks.

How to manage this?

Comment: Did you try `Frame.Content`?

Comment: You said that binding is not updating controls. Have you implemented the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) in your model?

Comment: Do you use x:Bind? Maybe you have popular mistake with binding Mode? By default it's `OneTime`. Change to One\Two Way

Comment: @AVKNaidu that works for me. I used reflection to get the instance of my Page, and also to invoke Bindings.Update() method.

Comment: @MatteoMarciano-MSCP Yes, my model have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented. If method that is updating model is async, the binding wouldn't update controls. With sync methods bindings works just fine.

Comment: I would suggest you post how you solved your problem as an answer and mark it as answered so that it can be useful for others.

Comment: If you are raising the PropertyChanged event asynchronously, you should use the Dispatcher to raise the event from the UI thread.